# Javascript horizontal scroll lock

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

How can i lock horizontal scrolling by using javascript, im not satisfied with overflow-x hidden, im trying to find a javascript option that locks the touchmove event on the x axis? Ive been trying to figure it out, so far i can only lock scrolling in both horizontal and vertical.

Comment: You can't really disable a scrollbar without removing it, but you can disable an event, like touch events. Which is it you're trying to do?

Comment: *"...im not satisfied with overflow-x hidden..."* Why not? What does having a scrollbar the user can't use buy you, other than arguably a poor user experience? (Although some touch devices won't show scrollbars anyway; others will...)

Comment: Little offtopic: I don;t know, what is this used for, maybe a game or some complicated ajax page. But locking horizontal scrolling isn't user friendly, when user access page, he expected and is accustomed that tha page scroll. So keep that in mind. Best regards :).

Comment: I'm trying to disable any horizontal touch event.

Comment: Yes i'm very well aware of it not being user friendly, but to further my knowledge i'd like to know if there's a way and how? rather than not know how to do so at all. Really appreciate and thankful for all the input

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<head>
<script>
var scrollpos = 0;
function onScroll(e){
 this.scrollLeft = scrollpos;
}
function init(){
 var scroller = document.getElementById('scroller');
 scroller.onscroll = onScroll;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
<div id="scroller" style="overflow:auto;"></div>
</body>
```